# Rails create table row on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this may be slightly confusing but i hope to make it work fine.

So at the moment i have this a table, Which looks like this,

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>EventName</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Initial Provider</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @newevents.each do |ne| %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= ne.id %></td>
        <td><%= ne.product_name %></td>
        <td><%= ne.description %></td>
        <td><%= ne.merchant_name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit Event", edit_event_path(ne.id), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
      </tr>

      <% end %>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

At the moment i have this loading in from `DBTable1`

Now, I'm wanting it so that when you click on the edit button. It will take you to a page where it can load in information from `DBTable1` but save the information into `DBTable2`

At the moment. `DBTable2` has a `DBTable1_id` field inside. But i haven't worked out fully how to use it. DBTable1 does have `has_one DBTable2` inside

How do i go about making this so that when you edit your actually creating a new row in `DBTable2` from the view?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to simply adjust the controller action (or create a new action) that acts just like "update", but creates a new one instead.

Actually, you can probably do this by changing `edit_event_path(ne.id)` to something else like, `create_event_path(ne.id)` or `new_event_path(ne.id)`.

Although, don't know enough about your app (including what it's routes are) to be sure.